# Arduino - Extracting Multiple Strings from Serial Read

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, programming, string

I am trying to write an Arduino code that reads a long string, example <11,22,33>, through the Serial Monitor and then stores the 11,22, and 33 into separate bins of a matrix array.

So the user could input: <11,22,33>
And the code would store the three entries into a matrix of strings:

```
matrix[0]=11;

matrix[1]=22;

matrix[2]=33;
```

Whenever I try to run the code the only result that's outputted is

```
matrix[0]=33;

matrix[1]=33;

matrix[2]=33;
```

But the strange part is when I put print commands after the Matrix[i]=data line in the code, the output shows the correct numbers! I'm not sure where the issue is and if somehow I made all entries the final entry. Any help is appreciated!

```
// Example 3 - Receive with start- and end-markers

const byte numChars = 32;
char data[numChars];    //data entry for appending Serial data
char *matrix[numChars]; //matrix of data entries
static byte i=0;  //matrix index

boolean newData = false;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("<Arduino is ready>");
}

void loop() {
    recvWithStartEndMarkers();
    showNewData();
    Serial.println(matrix[1]);
}

void recvWithStartEndMarkers() {
    static boolean recvInProgress = false;
    static byte ind = 0;  //data index
    char startMarker = '<';
    char midMarker = ',';
    char endMarker = '>';
    char rc;    //Serial read character


    while (Serial.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
        rc = Serial.read();

        if (rc == startMarker) {
            recvInProgress = true;  //if startMarker arrives then enter secondary if below
        }

        else if (recvInProgress) {  //begin appending characters if startMarker activated switch

            if (rc == midMarker) {  //if midMarker is reached...
                matrix[i]=data;     //append data to i-th entry in matrix
                i++;                //add to matrix index
                data[0] = '\0';     //clear data
                ind = 0;            //reset data index
            }
            else if (rc == endMarker) {     //if endMarker is reached...
                matrix[i]=data;             //append data to last entry in matrix (ensures last data is appended)
                data[ind] = '\0';           // terminate the string
                recvInProgress = false;     
                ind = 0;                    //reset counters for data and matrix
                i = 0;
                newData = true;
            }
            else {
                data[ind] = rc;           //eppend Serial character into data
                ind++;                    //add to data index
                if (ind >= numChars) {
                    ind = numChars - 1;
                }
            }  
        }
    }
}

void showNewData() {
    if (newData == true) {
        Serial.print("This just in ... ");
        Serial.println(matrix[0]);
        Serial.println(matrix[1]);
        Serial.println(matrix[2]);
        newData = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You define pointers for each value as :

```
char *matrix[numChars]; //matrix of data entries
```

However, in all cases you let it point to data:

```
matrix[i]=data;
```

Than you set the value starting from that address. So what happens is after you read the first value (11), and `matrix[0]` contains '11', than `matrix[1]` points to the same data which you write the value 22 to. And you do the same for 33. So you end up with 3 pointers to the same address (`data`) containing/overwriting the last value (33). So you get three times 33.

You should either continuing writing the string in `data` and refer to the correct part inside the string `data`.  If you want to do a `Serial.println`, you have to end the strings with `\0`, so the string `data` and matrix references should be:

```
index:    0   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
data:     1   1 \0  2  2 \0  3  3 \0
matrix:  [0]       [1]      [2]
i:        0         1        2
```

It will help if you change

```
matrix[i]=data;
```

to

```
matrix[i]=&(data[ind]);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your corrections. If I change matrix[i]=data to matrix[i]=&(data[ind]) what's printed is blank.

Comment: I didn't try the program, so it's a bit hard to verify out of my head. I think you should change the line at the end of my answer in both cases (if (rc == midMarker) and (rc == endMarker). Also in the midMarker case, I think you have to put i++ before the matrix[i] assignment.

However, I suggest you test this function not on an Arduino but in e.g. VisualStudio on a PC. Call the function and step with a debugger through the code so you can see immediately what is wrong.